# Pass a variable into ScrollTo

Tags: scrollto, getdate

[SOLVED](http://jsfiddle.net/9tY5T/7/)

Here's the result:

```
window.onload = function timeScroll()
{
var current_date = new Date();
hour_value = current_date.getHours();
var big_number = hour_value*833.3
$(window).scrollTop(big_number)
}
```

**PREVIOUS QUESTION**

I'm working on a page, that takes the time of day (hour) and uses that time to scroll to a particular point on the page. I multiply the `getHour` in order to get a variable I've called `big_number`. However, I can't seem to pass that variable into my scroll function.

This tells me that it's calculating the number correctly:

```
window.onload = function timeScroll()
{
var current_date = new Date();
hour_value = current_date.getHours();
var big_number = hour_value*833.3
window.alert(big_number);
}
```

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
window.onload = function timeScroll()
{
var current_date = new Date();
hour_value = current_date.getHours();
var big_number = hour_value*833.3
**scrollTo(x,big_number)**
}
```

Anything you've got helps. Also, here's the site live...

http://newmedia.emerson.edu/~caleb_ungewitter/weather/index.html

Comment: It would greatly help to show us your `scrollTo` function as well.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't have one that will let me pass the variable into it yet. I've tried `scrollTo(xpos,ypos)` but it won't let me insert the variable.

Comment: @winterblood `scrollTo` is a standard Javascript function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scrollTo

Comment: Your problem makes no sense, all functions let you pass variables. Maybe you need to round the number to an integer.

Comment: You're not setting `x`.

Comment: @Barmar I feel kind of stupid now, its been a long time since I've used Javascript without jQuery.

Comment: Hmm, I tried it in Chrome, it allows undefined and floating point arguments. But I don't know how portable that is.

Comment: Here's my jsFiddle. I've added it to the post: http://jsfiddle.net/9tY5T/5/.

Comment: Solved! Check out the jsFiddle. It won't let me solve it myself yet because of my reputation being so fresh.